# Adding a Teamcity schedule build trigger with Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, build, triggers, teamcity

I am trying to add a schedule trigger for my Teamcity build and the project settings format switched to Kotlin. I added to my settings.kts

```
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.triggers.schedule
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.triggers

project {
triggers {
        schedule {
            schedulingPolicy = daily {
                hour = 5
                minute = 30
            }
        triggerBuild = always()
        withPendingChangesOnly = false
        }
    }
}
```

But the trigger does not appear in Teamcity. What is the reason and what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Triggers are part of builds not projects. You should do it like this:

```
project {
  buildType {
    triggers {
      schedule {
        schedulingPolicy = daily {
          hour = 1
        }
        triggerBuild = always()
        enableQueueOptimization = false
      }
    }
  }  
}
```